# manually delete user profile via central admin - SP 2010 - Error Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I have some users that would like to delete from UPS in central admin.
I have farm admin access and also added the accts to Admin - user profile service but when i try to delete i get access denied.
Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Goto CA -> Service Application -> select UPS application (but don't click the link) -> Permission (at top ribbon). See whether you have permission?

Comment: I think i did this already but it didnt work .Will look at it again

Comment: Thanks Mark. I did that but still getting access denied

Comment: Also check this: Goto CA -> Service Application -> select UPS application (but don't click the link) -> Administrators. See whether your farm admin have full control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Powershell:

```
$spSite=Get-SPSite "http://servername"
$ctx=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($spSite)
$userName = "spUserToDelete";
$userProfileMgr = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]
$upm=New-Object $userProfileMgr($ctx)
$upm.RemoveUserProfile($userName)
```